# Find Nearest Point correspond to given point in scatter diagram

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, linear-algebra, graph-algorithm

[image]

I have Collection of address cordinates(latitude,longitude)  saved in database table as.

[image]

Based on User Current location for example user is at (55,65) , there should be an efficient algorithm for predicting nearest address currespond to user current location (55,65) for example in this case nearest address is Address13.
finding distance for every point is not efficient solution because  address data may grow to millions.

Comment: For the Nearest Neighbor problem in 2D, a kD-tree is a convenient solution. Lookup this term.

Comment: Since you will need to look at every point, any algorithm will need to be O(n). The simplistic algorithm is also O(n) so I do not see what you want. Will you do this calculation many times with the same points and varying "user current locations"? That may be made more efficient, but not looking for just one use current location.

Comment: This algorithm will be implemented in mobile app equipped with gps. As user traveling he open app , App will suggest nearest address(e.g Pizza Hut) base on his current location. so location can be changed as user move on.

Comment: If the addresses never change, it would be better to store your data in a k-d tree as @YvesDaoust suggested.

Comment: If you have million locations (?) you are probably using some external database GIS, which certainly support location queries.

Comment: If you have a dataset that simply a set of points, then you cannot have better than the `O(n)`. If your **data structure** is not simple list, then you might have a chance. As Yves mentioned, location queries have to do that. EG. If you search you street address in Google, it will infer that you are talking about you local area, infer where you request came from (using your IP probably) and display the most relevant data (aka not a simple list of 2D points with anywhere that matches the search query).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to implement some Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm on your data set, and then as you add data, add addresses to the MST. O(ElogV)

Then you will be able to search each nodes adjacency list to find the closest node instead of searching the entire table. O(E)

Or write a greedy algorithm that searches the graph. Give it the point and a radius to look out from, then it isn't looking at points that are >radius away.